# Angular - NgForm - FormControl is undefined

Tags: angular, angular-forms

I have a page where there is a simple `NgForm` form, I'm trying to disable a particular field after the page/view is loaded.

But I'm getting undefined exception:

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'disable' of undefined

**component.ts code:**

```
import { Component, ViewChild, OnInit, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
@Component({
  selector: 'sub',
  templateUrl: 'sub.component.html'
})

export class SubComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild('userForm') uf: NgForm;

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.uf);
    console.log(this.uf.controls['name']) // this is null
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log('kasdkfj')
    console.log(this.uf);
    console.log(this.uf.controls['name']) // this is null 
            this.uf.controls['name'].disable(); // Exception here
  }

  onSubmit(value: any) {
    console.log(this.uf.controls['name']) // But this is NOT null
            this.uf.controls['name'].disable(); // NO Exception, works perfectly
    console.log(value); 
  }
}
```

**HTML Code:**

```
<div class="container">
  <h2>Form Data</h2>

      <form #userForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(userForm.value)">
       <div class="form-group"> 
             <label>Name</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" ngModel> 
        </div><br/>
        <div ngModelGroup="address">
              <div class="form-group"> 
                  <label>City</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="city" ngModel> 
              </div><br/>
              <div class="form-group"> 
                  <label>Pin</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="pin" ngModel> 
              </div><br/>
              <div class="form-group"> 
                  <label>State</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="state" ngModel> 
              </div><br/>

        </div>
       <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" >Submit</button>
      </form>
  </div>
```

But same code when I do it on any button click or on submit it works without any issue.

**Question: How to disable one of the field after the form is initialized?**

[Stackblitz Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngform-qxz4vh?file=app/sub/sub.component.ts)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not a fan of this, but this "fixes" the problem.

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(this.uf.controls['name']) // this is null
      this.uf.controls['name'].disable(); // Exception here
    }, 0);
  }
```

Comment: Works great, thanks ! I was happy if there is kind of `AfterAfterViewInit` interface that do the trick instead of me

Comment: Finally something that worked !

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap it inside a setTimeout() to force it, or you can use [NgZone (for dirty check](https://blog.bitsrc.io/how-angular-uses-ngzone-zone-js-for-dirty-checking-faa12f98cd49))

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    setTimeout( () => {
      this.uf.controls['name'].disable();
    })
}
```

The main reason for this, I think, is that you are building your form in the wrong way. Take a look in the docs about [Reactive Forms](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms). You shoulkd build your form controls/groups in the component and not trying to retrieve them and the form itself via @ViewChild

Comment: Template driven forms use Reactive Forms under the cover.  I'm not sure I see anything wrong with what he is doing, but certainly if he created his form in the component it would fix the problem too.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following directive to the input element, and bind it to a variable in the component.

```html
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" ngModel [disabled]="nameDisabled">
```

Answer (score 0):

as you can find in [sources](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/f8096d499324cf0961f092944bbaedd05364eea1/packages/forms/src/directives/ng_form.ts) ngModel is registered in parent (and other ngModels reactions also) inside of a macrotask (resolvedPromise.then(...)). these handlings are done because ngModel can be exportedAs, and changes through parameters should change the component inners and then reflect back to parent template.

in template driven forms just add `disabled` attribute to form field that you want to disable on init like this `<input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" ngModel disabled>`. don't worry, it will only be "applied" once on element creation and won't affect future behavior.

if you don't like the method above `Promise.resolve().then(() => this.uf.controls['name'].disable())` inside of `ngAfterViewInit` will also work